# Autologout after logging in

Tags: ubuntu, shell, login, su

I have a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server.

I'm currently logged in as root, because I suddenly cannot log into my account anymore.

When I execute `su useraccount`, nothing happens.

The log file `auth.log` tells me the following:

```
Jan 25 14:51:43 server su[26174]: Successful su for useraccount by root
Jan 25 14:51:43 serversu[26174]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user useraccount by root(uid=0)
Jan 25 14:51:43 serversu[26174]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user useraccount
Jan 25 14:51:43 serversu[26174]: + /dev/ttyS0 root:useraccount
```

So, I can actually log in successfully, but I get kicked out right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your account's default shell has been changed.

Take a look at `/etc/passwd`. There should be a line similar to this one:

```
useraccount:x:1000:1000:username,,,:/home/useraccount:/bin/bash
```

If the last CSV is *not* your usual default shell, change it.

If your default shell it set correctly, examine the contents of `/home/useraccount/.bashrc` (or the equivalent of your shell) any every shell script it calls.

Comment: Well, that's the problem then: `/bin/false` means no shell at all. Ubuntu's default shell is `/bin/bash`. I have no idea how the shell might have changed.

Comment: That's not the only user where /bin/false is set. Well I will re-setup this server anyway. Maybe it really was caused by the last plesk update. I've got no idea. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! `/bin/false` is correct for non-human users that don't need a shell (e.g., `syslog`).

Comment: OMG !!!! you save me ♥